# Tracing all functions in executable conditionally, to find function of interest

Tags: pe, tools, dynamic-analysis, functions, tracing

I would like to alter the behavior of some executable (in my case, a videogame). One way of doing this is to hook function calls (e.g., a function like `Player::ReceiveDamage`) and adjust parameters/return values.

I know how to inject code and how to hook functions. **The challenge currently is to *find* the address of the function of interest**. The source code of the target is not available, neither are debug symbols.

An approach I successfully used before is the following:

1. Find all function addresses in the target executable (e.g., with IDA, radare2, Pyew, ...)
2. With the executable running, hook all functions
3. Black-list (and un-hook) functions that are called during moments that are not of interest
4. White-list functions that are called during moments of interest
5. Repeat steps (4,5) until function list is narrowed down sufficiently

Unfortunately, I have misplaced the code I was using for this process. I can re-write it, but I noticed that there is already an [enormous offering of tools and libraries](https://www.capstone-engine.org/showcase.html) that may do exactly what I need.

Performance is a challenge: logging all function calls in a videogame introduces significant overhead. I noticed previously that it would take some time for my old tool to black-list enough irrelevant functions for the target to become responsive. This likely makes [Frida](https://frida.re/) not a good choice, as it injects javascript.

**Does anyone know of a *performant* tool/library, supporting Windows and x64, that I can use to find functions of interest in a target executable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any binary dynamic instrumentation framework (like Intel pin, Frida, etc.)

https://github.com/SideChannelMarvels/Tracer/blob/master/TracerPIN/README.md

https://frida.re/docs/frida-trace/

Comment: Aha, the term I was looking for is "dynamic binary instrumentation"! Thank you very much. I've googled around a bit and indeed there appear to be some useful frameworks out there. I will update your answer to list a few of these.

For my use case probably these frameworks are overkill. I'll probably be quicker whipping up something myself compared to writing a plugin for one of those tools...